# After running shell script, variables lose their value

Tags: shell, variables

I have done a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
file_name=$1
state=`cat "$file_name" | grep "port protocol" | awk '{print $4}'`
echo $state
reason=`cat "$file_name" | grep "port protocol"`
echo $reason
```

This outputs the values $state and $reason.
However, when I run..

```
echo $state
```

..in the console it does not output nothing. It seems like the variable loses its value. Is this the normal behaviour or should I had something to the script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're running your script like `./script.sh` or `sh script.sh`, then this is the expected behaviour. Child processes cannot change the environment of their parent. The fact that you're running a shell script from a shell doesn't change this rule.

What you *can* do is source the script instead of executing it, to set those variables in the local environment:

```
. script.sh
```

This effectively runs the lines of the script in your current shell, so the variables will be set there.

While I've got your attention, I'd recommend making the following changes to your script:

```
#!/bin/sh
file_name=$1
state=$(awk '/port protocol/ {print $4}' "$file_name")
echo "$state"
reason=$(grep "port protocol" "$file_name")
echo "$reason"
```

In short, quote your variables, avoid useless calls to `cat` and use pattern matching in `awk` rather than piping `grep` to it.